# Bing Search search box cursor jumps to end when you type

Tags: search, bing

When I type in the search box in Bing the cursor jumps to the end. To reproduce:

1. do a search
2. when you are at results page, click on search query
3. box (the editbox with my query), at the middle  press a letter, e.g.
4. "Z"  cursor jumps to the end of query box (this is unwanted action)

How to I stop this silly behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to stop this annoying behavior. Hope this helps someone else.

1. Click Bing settings (the gear icon)
2. Turn off Search Suggestions. (its at the bottom of the general settings page)

That's it. Now you can refine your searches.

Comment: Link with current instructions: http://help.bing.microsoft.com/apex/index/18/en-US/10015

Comment: Man, it's mind boggling how inept Microsoft is!  You would think they would put their best foot forward when competing against Google. So many of their products are annoyingly buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is related to having javascript enabled on the 'security' tab under 'settings' in safari. When I unchecked the javascript box in settings it solved my problem. When I tried to reproduce this error on a different browser (firefox), I didn't have the same issue.